# How to put a bullet beside the heading elements as background image

Tags: css, xhtml, background-image

I'm using CSS and attempting to get what looks like a bullet point in the headings:

[image]

This is the exact image I want.

What I've done :

[image]

```css
h1,h2,h3 {
    background-image: url("the image link goes here");
}
```

anyone get any ideas I've tried moving it and stuff but it just isn't happening. Cheers.

Comment: also ive done background-image left and it puts it to the left and just about misses it -.- needs to be slightly more left

Comment: Add padding-left as well?

Answer (score 8):

You should set the [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) as well and also a left padding for the heading elements to push the text to the right:

```css
h1, h2, h3 {
  background: url("the image link goes here") 0 center no-repeat;
  padding-left: 15px; /* change this to fit your needs */
}
```

Note that I used the [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) property as a shorthand.

You can also achieve that by using [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore) pseudo-element to create the rectangle and position that within the headings as follows:

```css
h1:before,
h2:before,
h3:before {
  content: '■ ';
    position: relative;
    bottom: .1em;
    color: #666;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/quvz7/)**

Comment: cheers, worked :D ill accept your answer in 10 mins when its available :P

Comment: @user3339333 Your ten minutes are up.